# How to launch AWS CloudFormer stack to create the template of my infrastructure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I follow the [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html#launch-cloudformer) on how to create a CloudFormer stack in order to create a template of my infrastructure [to have as a starting point].

The stack tries to launch but the webserver EC2 instance fails to be created.

This is what it looks like...
[image]

In the creation wizard does not mention anything about a VPC. I do have the default one in this region but I do not know how to use it in this occasion.

Is it something extra that I must do??

Comment: It is possible that your Default VPC has been modified in some way. Are you able to start CloudFormer in a different Region?